# Laravel One to many CRUD Example

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, one-to-many

I am new to Laravel. I want to insert data to certain master detail tables with **Laravel4**. I searched all over the internet and could not find a proper solution.

I have two (plus one) tables as shown below.

**PO_HEADER**

```
PO_HEADER_ID
SUBJECT
PO_DATE
```

**PO_DETAIL**

```
PO_DETAIL_ID
PO_HEADER_ID
DESCRIPTION
AMOUNT
QTY
UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID
```

**UNIT_OF_MEASURE**

```
UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID
UNIT_OF_MEASURE
```

I should be able to insert the PO master along with as many PO detail records in one shot while pressing a **SAVE BUTTON**. Unit of measure in the detail section should be a drop down list (filled from the `UNIT_OF_MEASURE` table)

Kindly suggest how to achieve this easily. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your models being set up correctly:

```
class PurchaseOrder extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'subject',
        'date'
    ];

    public function detail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('PurchaseOrderDetail');
    }
}

class PurchaseOrderDetail extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'description',
        'amount',
        'qty'
    ];

    protected $with = [
        'unitOfMeasure',
    ];

    public function header()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('PurchaseOrder');
    }

    public function unitOfMeasure()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('UnitOfMeasure');
    }
}

class UnitOfMeasure extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function lineItems()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('PurchaseOrderDetail');
    }
}
```

You also need to set up your migrations using the proper settings, like so:

```
//migration for purchaseorder table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('purchaseorders', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('subject');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

//migration for purchaseorderdetail table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('purchaseorderdetails', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('purchaseorder_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('unitofmeasure_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('purchaseorder_id')->references('id')->on('purchaseorders');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->float('amount');
        $table->float('qty');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

//migration for unitsofmeasure table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('unitsofmeasure', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

That should get you fairly close to what you need, I hope. :) You can then query for your items like so:

```
$po-details = PurchaseOrderDetail::with(['purchaseOrder', 'unitOfMeasure')->find($id);
```

This is what an overly simplified controller method may look like:

```
class PurchaseOrderController
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $purchaseOrders = PurchaseOrder::with('detail')->find($id);

        return View::make('purchaseOrder.show', compact('purchaseOrders'));
    }
}
```

And then your view:
    
    
        
            @foreach ($purchaseOrders as $purchaseOrder)
            
                @foreach ($purachseOrder->detail as $lineItem)
                    
                @endforeach
            @endforeach

Comment: Could you please explain how to setup the **View** and **Controller**? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That quickly becomes more complicated, depending on your needs. I will try to add a simplified version above.

Comment: Could you please explain how to Setup **VIEW** for the **CRUD**? Thanks.